# How do I split two controllers to two Swagger definitions

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, swashbuckle

So, I am making a pretty big API in an ASP.NET Web API project. I wanted to have multiple definitions to make sure categoriers are split correctly, with the use of tags within the definitions.

In my Startup file, I do the following:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(d =>
        {
            d.SwaggerDoc("main", new OpenApiInfo
            {
                Title = "Main",
                Version = "v1",
                Description = "The main information",
                Contact = new OpenApiContact
                {
                    Name = "itsfinniii"
                }
            });

            d.SwaggerDoc("school", new OpenApiInfo
            {
                Title = "School",
                Version = "v1",
                Description = "School stuff",
                Contact = new OpenApiContact
                {
                    Name = "itsfinniii"
                }
            });

            d.DocInclusionPredicate((name, api) => true);
        });
```

Then, in my MainController.cs I do the following:

```
    [Route("api")]
    [Tags("Main Endpoints")]
    [ApiExplorerSettings(GroupName = "main")]
    [ApiController]
    public class MainController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("alive")]
        [ApiExplorerSettings(GroupName = "v1")]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status204NoContent)]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Alive()
        {
            return new NoContentResult();
        }
    }
```

And in my SchoolController.cs I do the following:

```
    [Route("api/school")]
    [Tags("School Endpoints")]
    [ApiExplorerSettings(GroupName = "school")]
    [ApiController]
    public class MainController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("hello-world")]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
        public async Task<string> Alive()
        {
            return "Hello World!";
        }
    }
```

However, both tags and both endpoints appear within both definitions. How could I make it so that only those that belong to main appear in the main definition, and nowhere else, and that those that belong to school only appear in the school definition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove below code from your startup:

```
d.DocInclusionPredicate((name, api) => true);
```

Besides, remove this line from your main controller Alive():

```
[ApiExplorerSettings(GroupName = "v1")]
```

In startup, I specify one or more Swagger endpoints  like :

```
 app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
                {
                    c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/main/swagger.json", "main");
                    c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/school/swagger.json", "school");
                });
```

result:

[image]

You can read [Swashbuckle.AspNetCore](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore) to know  more.